# Turning flow rate to flow speed and the vectoral properties

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow

So if flow rate is a scalar property and we can turn flow rate into velocity with Q=A*v(Q flow rate A area v velocity), and if velocity is a vectoral property, what exactly in this equation decides the vectors directions? What I am trying to find specifically is when I pour some water from a kettle to a inclined flat plate and if I know the flow rate out of the kettle, does the angle of the plate effect the speed?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply turn a flow rate into a vector quantity.

In a flowing fluid the flow velocity is a vector field. That is, at every point in the fluid there is a velocity vector and the velocity is a function of position, and possibly also of time if the flow is not in a steady state.

If you have some infinitesimal vector area $d\mathbf A$ at some position $\mathbf x$ where the velocity is $\mathbf v(\mathbf x)$ then the flow rate through that area is:

$$ dQ = \mathbf v \cdot d\mathbf A $$

For some surface in the fluid the flow rate through that surface is obtained by integrating the equation above over the surface:

$$ Q = \int_S \mathbf v \cdot d\mathbf A $$

The problem is that information is lost when you evaluate this integral. Many different velocity vectors could give the same dot product, and many different dot products could give the same value for the integral. So if you are starting from the total flow rate it is simply impossible to reconstruct the flow velocity field.

In your particular experiment you could probably obtain a useful approximation for the flow velocity of the fluid coming out of the kettle by treating it as a uniform flow i.e. assume the flow velocity is the same everywhere and is parallel to the centre line through the spout. Whether the approximation is good enough to be useful is going to depend on the details of your experiment.